# Efficient way to generate alphanumeric number which is not already in list

Tags: java

This is my code is there any efficient way other than this

```
        List<String> numbers = Arrays.asList("1234acb","djnjwd222","djwnqfe456");
        boolean unique = false;
        while(!unique){
            final String ALPHA_NUMERIC = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789";
            StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
            int length = 15;
            while (length-- != 0) {
                int character = (int)(Math.random()*ALPHA_NUMERIC.length());
                builder.append(ALPHA_NUMERIC.charAt(character));
            }
            if(!numbers.contains(builder.toString())){
                unique = true;
            }
        }
```

Comment: Is there a problem with doing it this way? There are certainly ways of speeding this up but whether this makes sense very much depends on the use-case.

Comment: That should be efficient enough for most practical purposes. The chance of generating a duplicate string is so small that it's unlikely to ever happen.

Comment: Note that with numbers at it is, there won't be a collision since your code generate a string of 15 char while all your list member are far shorter than that. Even if you store the previously generated string and compare against it, the probability of collision is still astronomically small, the output space is 36^15, roughly 2^77, with a billion items the probability of collision is 3e-6

Comment: Arguably, there are alot of ways: `ThreadLocalRandom.current().longs().parallel().mapToObj(l -> Long.toUnsignedString(l, 36)).flatMap(s -> Arrays.stream(s.split(""))).limit(15).collect(Collectors.joining())`.

Comment: Thanks, @Martheen that number list is just for example I have a very big list of numbers in my database every time I insert a record I want to generate a new unique number which is not in the database already. collision chance is very less but still chance

Comment: @Monikaverma Benchmark the code I wrote in the comments section and let me know if it performs well. It exploits parallelism so it might be fast. I didn't benchmark it before posting.

Comment: If we're dealing with DB anyway, just use UUID, your DB should already support it natively, no need to go back and forth between app & DB nor checking it afterwards, Java's UUID result space is 122 bit, at one *trillion* items the collision chance is still 9e-14. The CPU, RAM and disk I/O involved should be very minimal since generating UUID is already as optimized as possible

Comment: Thanks, @AniketSahrawat your solution seems to be faster

Comment: @Monikaverma I just tested it, if you run that code without `parallel`, it would be 10x faster ~ UUID generation speed but it includes all the 36 chars unlike UUID

Comment: All the solutions focusing only a generating a number faster but I think the focus should also how to guarantee uniqueness

Comment: @Monikaverma That can simply be achieved if you declare `numbers` as `Set<String>` and use `while (!numbers.add(ThreadLocalRandom.current().longs().mapToObj(l -> Long.toUnsignedString(l, 36)).flatMap(s -> Arrays.stream(s.split(""))).limit(15).collect(Collectors.joining())));`

Comment: @AniketSahrawat - I suggest you add your comment as an answer. Don't sacrifice this much buddy! It makes me emotional. Let's complete with each other in a healthy manner.

Comment: @ArvindKumarAvinash It depends on the requirements. `Set` makes perfect sense here and I believe that it would be faster than list in this case. Also, don't worry about my comment, I didn't put any thoughts into it. I was doing something and I came up here because I got bored. I didn't spend any time answering that. I would request you to copy that comment and write it as your answer if you see it fit :)

Comment: @AniketSahrawat - Let me know your thoughts on this code which produces 10000 random integers. `long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
  Set<Integer> set = new HashSet<>();
  Random random = new Random();
  while (set.size() != 10000) {
   set.add(random.nextInt(10000));
  }
  System.out.println(System.currentTimeMillis() - start);

  start = System.currentTimeMillis();
  List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>();
  for (int i = 0; i < 10000; i++) {
   list.add(i);
  }
  Collections.shuffle(list);
  System.out.println(System.currentTimeMillis() - start);`

Comment: @AniketSahrawat - Instead of editing my last comment, I deleted it accidentally. You can infer whatever I wanted to say from the code given above.

Comment: @ArvindKumarAvinash Actually, that's a wrong way of comparing them. See: https://pastebin.com/3XyW2i0g The code I pasted will give you a hint of what will perform better. Apart from that, if a true benchmark is needed then it can only be written using jmh.

Comment: @AniketSahrawat - `if a true benchmark is needed then it can only be written using jmh.` - Undoubtedly true. However, I didn't understand how pastebin.com/3XyW2i0g will produce a list/set of 10000 random unique integers. The code which I have given above does that.

Comment: @ArvindKumarAvinash Sir, it's not about generating random numbers. Anyways, see: https://pastebin.com/myJHTcXb with random integers.

Comment: @AniketSahrawat - In the case of `list`,  you do not need to generate a random number and add the same; just add the number and leave it to `Collections.shuffle(list)` to randomize all the numbers. Anyway, we can continue our discussion using our personal channels (LinkedIn, phone etc.); let's not spam this question.

Comment: @ArvindKumarAvinash I know I shouldn't be stretching this. Sorry sir :) Hope you don't mind because I am like your son :) I gave it some thought and here is a performance difference between the answer that is written below vs my code(slightly modified) https://pastebin.com/qUvLmhQi

Comment: @ArvindKumarAvinash Yes that is one wrong way of comparing set vs list. Set is very fast than list for this case because it is optimized for uniqueness.

Answer (score 1):

## Yet another update

Thanks to Joni for reviewing my last update. He rightly pointed out that the code in the last update could use a symbol only once. The following solution solves that issue. It also handles the uniqueness in an improved way.

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<String> numbers = Arrays.asList("1234acb", "djnjwd222", "djwnqfe456");
        boolean unique = false;

        // Generate the List of string each having only one char from a-z 0-9
        List<String> list = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789".chars()
                                .mapToObj(c -> String.valueOf((char) c))
                                .collect(Collectors.toList());

        // Shuffle the elements of the list
        Collections.shuffle(list);

        //Get nano seconds from JVM
        long nano = System.nanoTime();
        StringBuilder str = new StringBuilder();
        while (nano != 0) {
            // Get the string (char) from `list` at the index = last digit of `nano`
            str.append(list.get((int) (nano % 10)));

            // Make nano smaller by one tenth
            nano /= 10;
        }

        System.out.println(str);

        // Check if `numbers` contains `str`
        if (!numbers.contains(str)) {
            unique = true;
        }

        System.out.println(unique ? "Unique" : "Not unique");
    }
}
```

**A sample run:**

```
a5ago6u393g6frf
Unique
```

## Update

As pointed out by [Joni](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63326710/efficient-way-to-generate-alphanumeric-number-which-is-not-already-in-list/63326758#comment111978956_63326758), the generated string in the original answer contained only `0-9 a-f`. The following solution solves that issue:

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<String> numbers = Arrays.asList("1234acb", "djnjwd222", "djwnqfe456");
        boolean unique = false;

        // Generate the List of string each having only one char from a-z 0-9
        List<String> list = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789".chars()
                                .mapToObj(c -> String.valueOf((char) c))
                                .collect(Collectors.toList());

        // Shuffle the elements of the list
        Collections.shuffle(list);

        // Get a string by joining the first 16 elements of the list
        String str = String.join("", list.subList(0, 16));
        System.out.println(str);
        
        // Check if `numbers` contains `str`
        if (!numbers.contains(str)) {
            unique = true;
        }

        System.out.println(unique ? "Unique" : "Not unique");
    }
}
```

**A sample run:**

```
miblz0o61r89xdg5
Unique
```

## Original answer:

You can use [UUID](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/UUID.html) to generate a random alphanumeric string. Note that this string contains `-` which you can replace with an empty string and then get the first 16 characters from the resulting string.

```
import java.util.UUID;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(UUID.randomUUID().toString().replace("-", "").substring(0, 16));
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
68477a8bf3084a42
```

Comment: The only problem I can see here is that you only generate hexadecimal digits 0-9 a-f, leaving letters g to z unused, but I don't see that as a sufficient reason to downvote...

Comment: Thanks, @Joni for the pointing it out. You are right.

Comment: The question was if there's an **efficient way** to generate strings that are **not in the list** already. Could you expand the answer so that it explains why this is (more) efficient than what they already have, and how it guarantees that the generated strings are unique (not already in the list)?

Comment: @Joni - I've written an update. I would appreciate your reviewing the same.

Comment: The code in the update can use a symbol only once. That means the number of unique strings it can generate is a lot lower than what the OP can generate with the code they already have. That said, the OP's question is about generating unique strings and *guaranteeing they are unique*, you're not doing the second part

Comment: @Joni - `The code in the update can use a symbol only once. That means the number unique strings it can generate is a lot lower than the code the OP already has.` - Wow! This is really genius of you! It didn't even come to my mind. I'll certainly rework my solution based on this feedback.

Comment: @Joni - May I request you to review yet another update whenever you manage some time to do so?

Comment: The latest approach is interesting but it suffers from the same problem as the first approach with UUID: `list.get((int) (nano % 10))` will only use the first 10 symbols in the list

Comment: @Joni - Thanks a lot for taking time to review it. It will only use the first 10 symbols in the list but the list is already shuffled so unlike UUID, which is limited to `0-9 a-f`, it can have any character from `0-9 a-z`. However, I see you have pointed out another interesting thing that I need to work on.

Comment: That is true, but not allowing use of symbols other than the first 10 greatly reduces the number of unique strings you can generate, even if you choose the 10 symbols randomly every time. By the way I'm not the one who downvoted, I thought the answer was OK-ish as it was

Comment: @Joni - Yes, I got the point and I'm already thinking about a solution to that . I know you didn't downvote. Someone who has been helping this community so great and also helping contributors like me to improve answer can not do it silently.

Comment: @Joni Aniket's answer is really good tbh, I copy pasted it as mine.

Answer (score 1):

Copy pasting [@AniketSahrawat](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6099347/aniket-sahrawat)'s comment before mods clear up the section. The original post is available on [pastebin](https://pastebin.com/qUvLmhQi) and the comment by user Aniket is/was available [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63326710/efficient-way-to-generate-alphanumeric-number-which-is-not-already-in-list#comment111983784_63326710):

```
Set<String> numbers = new HashSet<>();
while (!numbers.add(ThreadLocalRandom.current().ints()
    .flatMap(l -> Integer.toString(l, 36).chars())
    .limit(15)
    .collect(StringBuilder::new,
        StringBuilder::appendCodePoint,
        StringBuilder::append).toString()));
```

I would be happy to delete this answer if Aniket decides to post it. Performance difference in another answer by Arvind vs Aniket is:

```
59968 <- another answer
191   <- this answer
```

**EDIT:**

I just tested this answer with `UUID.randomUUID().toString().replace("-", "").substring(0, 16)` and it turns out that this answer is faster than `UUID.randomUUID().toString().replace("-", "").substring(0, 16)` using `Set<String>` as backing data type. Here is it's [pastebin](https://pastebin.com/f0wJm8Kg).

Comment: The first Pastebin code might be faster than Arvind's answer but the second one is a close call and you can't predict whether its behavior will remain the same when micro benchmarking is done.